# Comparing certain numbers with Fibonacci numbers in R

Tags: r, for-loop, fibonacci

I'm newbie in R language and I'm trying to Identify whether n (certain of numbers) is a Fibonacci number and whether it has an integer square root to return boolean.

I have got the Fibonacci numbers works but when I'm trying to compare them to get a boolean for the Fibonacci number and square root and store them in vector it didn't work.

For example:

```
number <- c(0,1,1,2,4,6) 

Fibonacci <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)

squareRoot <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Here is the code:

```
fibvec <- NULL
fibonacci <- c(1,1)
number <- c(1:6)

for (i in number) {
  fibonacci<-c(fibonacci,fibonacci[i-1]+fibonacci[i-2])  ## to get fibonacci numbers

  for (j in fibonacci) {
    fibvew <- c(fibvec[j])
  }
  if (seq(number) == seq(fibonacci)) {
    #???
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your `for` loop. The first value of `i` is 1, then you try to add `fibonacci[0] + fibonacci[-1]` but neither of these exist.

Comment: Also in your second `for` loop you keep overwriting `fibvew`, which might be a typo, using the `c` function. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: The actual (number) is the wondrous numbers, which when I generate the sequence of numbers for values of n from 1 to 30 and store it in (wondrous), then check whether (wondrous) numbers are a Fibonacci number and whether it has an integer square root by returning a boolean

Comment: fibvec, to store the boolean values in it like if the number == fubinacci number then it will store TRUE and end to be like fibvec (TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a loop and the `numbers` library has a `fibonacci` function:

```
library(numbers)

number <- c(0,1,1,2,4,6)
fseq <- numbers::fibonacci(length(number), sequence = T)
Fibonacci <- number == fseq # number %in% fseq
squareRoot <- sqrt(number) %% 1 == 0
```

If you want to do an element-wise comparison the above will work. If you want to know if any `number` is in the sequence use the comment: `number %in% fseq`.

The `%%` is the modulo operator, which returns the remainder after division. If this is zero then the square root is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try `tail`+ `sum` to update `fibonacci`, e.g.,

```
fibonacci <- c(0, 1)
number <- c(3:6)

for (i in number) {
  fibonacci <- append(fibonacci, sum(tail(fibonacci, 2)))
}
```

such that

```
> fibonacci
[1] 0 1 1 2 3 5
```

Comment: I got the Fibonacci numbers working but when I compare the number to a certain of numbers to return TRUE or FALSE, it didn't work